# Dynamic choose condition in XSLT

Tags: xslt

How to use the choose condition in XSLT when the below requirement is needed

```
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="contains(@name,'top %d holdings' ) ">
<!--code-->
</xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
```

It should select all the data containing....

1. top 5 holdings
2. top 10 holdings
3. top 30 holdings
4. top 27 holdings
5. top * holdings

Answer (score 1):

If you were using XSLT2.0 here, you could use the **matches** function which allows you to match text by means of a regular expression

```
<xsl:when test="matches(@name, '.*top \d+ holdings.*')">
```

On the other hand, if you were using XSLT 1.0, then the **matches** function is not available. One way you could do it in your very specific case is extract the text before "holdings" that occurs before "top" and check it is a number:

```
<xsl:when test="string(number(substring-before(substring-after(@name, 'top '), ' holdings' ) )) != 'NaN'">
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't find `top * holdings`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [substring-before()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-substring-before) and [substring-after()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-substring-after) to get the text between `top` and `holdings`, and then use the [translate()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-translate) function to remove numbers and the `*` character, and then verify that the result is an empty string.

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when 
       test="translate(
               substring-before(substring-after(@name, 'top '), ' holdings' ),
               '0123456789*', 
               '') = '' ">
        <!--code-->
    </xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
```